# Find a solution to $z+e^{-z}=a$ where $a>1$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, exponential-function

Find a solution to $z+e^{-z}=a$ where $a>1$.

I have tried many manipulations with little success. I don't see how I can solve this for $z$. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated. I think that there is one real solution to this equation and that it will be in the right half plane.

Comment: Numerical approximations allowed or only closed form solutions?

Comment: If $a=k-\log k$ then $z=-\log k$ will be the solution

Answer (score 3):

This is what's known as a transcendental equation, which has no elementary closed form. It can, however be solved in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

$\begin{align*}z + e^{-z} &= a\\ze^{z} + 1 &= ae^z\\e^z(z-a) &= -1\\e^{z-a}(z-a)&= -e^{-a}\\ z-a &= W(-e^{-a})\\z &= W(-e^{-a}) + a\end{align*}$

Answer (score 0):

There is no elementary solution to that. Wolfram Alpha produces
$$z = W(-e^{-a})+a $$
which involves the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but this probably doesn't make you much wiser in practice -- you would just solve it numerically.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you can write $$z=W(-e^{-a})+a$$ but this fails to shed any real light on the problem. There aren't really any algebraic manipulations that you can do to work out anything useful. You can use numerical approximation techniques if you want a decimal answer though.

Comment: I don't get it : yes the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) answers to many questions associated to the problem, it is well studied, its power series, the convergence of some iterative algorithms, the different branches, the fact that it is a transcendental equation, etc..

Comment: What do you not get?

Comment: your answer : in my opinion the fact that it reduces to the Lambert function fully answers to the problem, it is complicated, transcendental, but well-studied.

Comment: That's fair. I'm an algebraist, and it makes me sad that you can't do some incredibly clever thing to get an answer, but that's reasonable.